# In the index, after page number, how to put section number followed by column number?

Tags: indexing

hello respected every one.

I am writing a book with multiple column format in latex. I have included the chapter index. My knowledge is very small about it but I am learning gradually. I have seen that the list in index is appearing (so far) in two column format.

My questions are:

(1) is it possible if i wish, to create the index with 3 columns or more? Will it be suitable? what do you suggest?

(2) Moreover, as I said that I am writing the book in multiple column format, so I am willing to know if it is possible that in the index list, after the subject name, followed by page number , there will be another customization as s/m where s/m denotes the appearance of the subject in that specified page in the section number s under the column number m.

For example, suppose the word "apple" is in page 20 , section 3.2 in column number 3. And I want the appearance of the word "apple" would be like "apple, 20, 3.2/3".

How simply can we do that ? please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add a full MWE of your document?

Comment: When you refer to a *multiple column*, you are using the `twocolumn` option? Or the `multicol` package ?

Comment: Other thing, are you using `makeindex` or `xindy` for sorting your index?

Comment: I am using     \multicol package. And I am not using \makeindex or \xindy. As I don't know any thing about them